# Admob House Ads Interstitials: How to expand html ad to fullscreen

Tags: html, admob, fullscreen, interstitial

I've just implemented interstitials house ads in my app successfully. The problem which I have is about the size of the fullscreen banner I receive.

Somebody knows how to specify in the html document to fill the screen with my banner?

Any html template for interstitials?